# Removing items in an array in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In the game I'm trying to create, I have objects which the player can touch. If these objects are touched, the stage would be cleared. Since there are more than one objects, I put everything inside an array and I need to remove the touched object from the array so that it will only call stage clear once the array is empty. This is the code I currently am trying to use:

```
if event.phase == "ended" then
    for i=#objArray,0,-1 do
        if(#objArray ~= 0) then
            objArray[i] = table.remove(objArray)
        else
            storyboard.gotoScene("ClearStage", fade, 400)
            timer.pause(timerCount)
        end
    end
end
```

The problem with this is that the array immediately becomes 0 after it passes the loop once.  Also, I don't think i should be the value inside the objArray. It should be the touched object instead but I'm not sure how to implement that. I need to do something like:

```
if objArray > 0 then
      --remove touched object from array
else
      --go to clear
end
```

I'm just starting working with arrays and loops so I'm still very confused so I hope someone can help me with this. How can I tell my array to remove just the touched object while the array is greater than 0?

Actually, never mind. I figured out the solution while tweaking with my code. Here's the code I ended up with:

```
if(#objArray ~= 0) then
        objArray[0] = table.remove(objArray)
        if(#objArray == 0) then
            storyboard.gotoScene("ClearStage", fade, 400)
            timer.pause(timerCount)
        end
    end
```

Basically, I didn't need the for loop anymore and I used 0 index(if my understanding's correct) like so: objArray[0] to remove the object from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you probably delete which object you touched right.try this

```
display.remove(event.target);event.target=nil
```

after removing check your array size

```
if #objArray == 0 then
    --here you do your array clear work
    table.remove (objArray )
 end
```